# Hibernate: Where to map an additional column in a relating table?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I have two tables in a one-to-many relationship mapped by Hibernate:

```
<hibernate-mapping> 
  <class name="Class1" table="TABLE_1" dynamic-update="true">
    <meta attribute="implement-equals">true</meta>   
    <cache usage="read-write"/>

    <id name="id" column="KEY_1" length="5" >

....
    </id>
    <property name="property1a" column="COLUMN_1A" type="string" length="10" />
    <property name="property1b" column="COLUMN_1B" type="string" length="10" />
    <set name="properties2Set" table="TABLE_2" lazy="true" fetch="subselect" cascade="all">
        <key column="FOREIGN_KEY_1"/>
        <composite-element class="Class2">
            <property name="property2a" type="string" column="COLUMN_2A"/>
            <property name="property2b" type="string" column="COLUMN_2B"/>
            <property name="property2c" type="string" column="COLUMN_2C"/>    
    </composite-element>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Class1 looks like:

```
public class Class1
{
    //... Here the definitions of property1a, property1b

    private Set<Class2> properties2Set = new HashSet<Class2>();


    public Set<Class2> getProperties2Set() 
    {
        return properties2Set;
    }

    public void setProperties2Set(Set<Class2> properties2Set) 
    {
        this.properties2Set = properties2Set;
    }

    // ... Definitions of equals() and hashCode() 
}
```

Class2 contains properties `property2a, property2b, property2c`. There is a constraint

```
CONSTRAINT PK_OLD PRIMARY KEY (FOREIGN_KEY_1, COLUMN_2A, COLUMN_2B, COLUMN_2C)
```

I want to add to the table the column

```
COLUMN_ID_NUMBER NUMBER(5) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

change the constraint into

```
CONSTRAINT PK_NEW PRIMARY KEY (FOREIGN_KEY_1, COLUMN_ID_NUMBER)
```

and generate values of `COLUMN_ID_NUMBER` in order not to violate the constraint.

Where to add the property that would be mapped into `COLUMN_ID_NUMBER` and how to generate its values? Is it possible to leave the structure of `Class2` unchanged?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. What is the reason you are adding the new column COLUMN_ID_NUMBER ? is it a composite key attribute or something? is it a new column in the DB table? FYI: If it you are adding composite key, then all the keys have to be mentioned in the mapping.

Comment: Yes, COLUMN_ID_NUMBER is to form a part of a composite key. I want to add a column in order to get a primary key composed of two columns and to enable to insert nulls into other columns.